# Output the names of a nested list based on their corresponding elements

Tags: r, list, nested-lists

How do I output the names of a nested list that correspond to their elements? As in this example, I want to output  if ("cat") then "foo" ,  if("dog") then "bar".. etc. I would like to avoid using multiple if else statements , since there could be 100 variables

```
parms <- list(
  "foo"    = list( id = "cat",    range = c(1,10)),
  "bar"    = list( id = "dog",    range = c(20,30)),
  "var"    = list( id = "mouse",  range = c(40,50))
)
```

Comment: Why don't you create a key of the list names and the required value. For instance, `sapply(parms, "[[", "id")`?

Comment: You're asking a brand new question there. Please try identifying what you need (for your new question), what you have tried and where it had failed.

Comment: By the two new questions you ask (how to get the position of "cat" within the list and how to get "foo" from range = c(1, 10)) I can infer that a list may not be the ideal data structure. Have you tried `unlist(parms)`?

Comment: @PavoDive Ok thanks, I will try that and restructure to see how it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the recommendation in the comment by @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 :

```
names(grep("cat", sapply(parms, "[[", "id"), value = TRUE))
[1] "foo"
```

What is in there:

- The `sapply(parms, "[[", "id")` part creates a named vector with each `id` (cat, dog, ...) and the name of each nested list (foo, bar, ...)
- The `grep` returns a one element named vector with the coincident element and its name.
- The `names` part extracts the name (foo in our case) out of the named vector.

Comment: Thats great, thanks! Is it similar to extracting the corresponding ranges? cat: range c(1,10).. etc

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function which handles your request dynamically.

```
get_names <- function(x, name, value) {
  names(Filter(function(p) all(p[[name]] == value), x))
}

get_names(parms, 'id', 'cat')
#[1] "foo"

get_names(parms, 'range', c(1, 10))
#[1] "foo"

get_names(parms, 'range', c(40, 50))
#[1] "var"
```

---

If you want to exclude `name` dependency from the function.

```
get_names <- function(x, value) {
  names(Filter(function(p) any(unlist(p) == value), x))
}

get_names(parms, 'cat')
#[1] "foo"
get_names(parms, 40)
#[1] "var"
```

---

**EDIT**

```
get_names <- function(x, name, value) {
  names(x)[sapply(x, `[[`, name) %in% value]  
}

get_names(parms, 'id', c('cat', 'dog'))
#[1] "foo" "bar"
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, As a followup to the above question, is there a way pass a vector to value? like
get_names(parms, 'id', c('cat', 'dog')) and get the output as c('foo', 'bar') ?